# Error when running Helm Chart with environment variables

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am creating a [Helm Chart](https://helm.sh/docs/) (v3) for a Kubernetes Deployment.
In the deployment.yaml I am defining some environment variables

```
spec:
  ...  
    env:
      - name: GRAPHITE_ENABLED
        value: {{ .Values.env.graphiteEnabled }}
      - name: GRAPHITE_HOSTNAME
        value: {{ .Values.env.graphiteHostname }}
```

and specifying values for these environment variables in values.yaml

```
env:
  graphiteEnabled: "false"
  graphiteHostname: "localhost"
```

When running the Chart using this command

```
helm install --debug api-test ./rest-api
```

the following error is caused:

> Error: Deployment in version "v1beta1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: v1beta1.Deployment.Spec: v1beta1.DeploymentSpec.Template: v1.PodTemplateSpec.Spec: v1.PodSpec.Containers: []v1.Container: v1.Container.Env: []v1.EnvVar: v1.EnvVar.Value: ReadString: expects " or n, but found f

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turned out the issue was caused by the value `"false"`.

After a `--dry-run` I saw that the output of the generated values was

```
- name: GRAPHITE_ENABLED
  value: false
```

But the environment variable must be defined with quotes.

Using the [`quote` function](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/) for the value in the values.yaml fixed the issue

```
- name: GRAPHITE_ENABLED
  value: {{ .Values.env.graphiteEnabled | quote }}
```

which generated the following output

```
- name: GRAPHITE_ENABLED
  value: "false"
```