# How to pass dynamic argument to a helm chart from values

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a process running in a ubuntu docker container which I run with the following command:

```
docker container_name:latest -ms server_name -msp server_port -ma server_address -ir receiver_ip_address -pr receiver_port -s sleep_time -r true
```

An Entrypoint has been defined in the docker recipe from which the container starts and to which the arguments passed by the docker run are added.

With the following deployment.yaml:

```
 containers:
  - name: container_name
    image: {{ .Values.global.container_name}}:{{ .Values.global.container_name.tag }}
    args:
      {{  range .Values.global.container_args }}
       - {{ . }}
      {{ end }}
```

And the following values.yaml:

```
global:
 container_name: ['-ms','server_name','-msp','server_port','-ma','server_address',' ir',' receiver_ip_address', '-pr','receiver_port' , '-s','sleep_time','-r' 'true']
```

In particular, the r and s flags are passed from the values.yaml file as boolean and integer inside singlequote like also server_port.

I get the following error:

```
INSTALLATION FAILED: Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: v1.Deployment.Spec: v1.DeploymentSpec.Template: v1.PodTemplateSpec.Spec: v1.PodSpec.Containers: []v1.Container: v1.Container.Args: []string: ReadString: expects " or n, but found 1, error found in #10 byte of ...|","-msp",server_port,"-ma","|..., bigger context ...|args":["-ms","server_name","-msp",server_port,"-ma","server_address","-m|...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the integer and boolean values ​​from the value.yaml file and inserting random strings I noticed that the pod was running (with application error) and the previous error did not appear.

Trying to figure out the reason for this problem I found this post:

[Error when running Helm Chart with environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59324815/error-when-running-helm-chart-with-environment-variables)

I changed the deploy.yaml template line from:

```
 containers:
 - name: container_name
   image: {{ .Values.global.container_name}}:{{ .Values.global.container_name.tag }}
   args:
    {{  range .Values.global.container_args }}
     - {{ . }}
    {{ end }}
```

to:

```
  containers:
  - name: container_name
    image: {{ .Values.global.container_name}}:{{ .Values.container_name.tag}}
    args:
      {{  range .Values.global.container_args}}
       - {{ . | quote }}
      {{ end }}
```

using the [**quote**](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/) function.